# Replace text in multiple lines

Tags: bash, replace, output, lines

i try to replace some text parts of my bash output. My bash output looks like:

```
vserver            policyname  clientmatch  rorule rwrule superuser
------------------ ----------- ------------ ------ ------ ---------
Vserver1           Volume1     Host1        sys    never  sys
Vserver2           Volume2     Host2        sys    never  sys
Vserver3           Volume3     Host3        sys    none   never
Vserver4           Volume4     Host4        sys    never  sys
Vserver5           Volume5     Host5        sys    sys    sys
```

I want to replace:

sys with true
none with false
never with false

How I can do that? My output is showing me all lines at once and this try doesn't work for me:

```
RED_TEXT=$(tput setaf 1)
GREEN_TEXT=$(tput setaf 2)
BOLD_TEXT=$(tput bold)
RESET_TEXT=$(tput sgr0)

true=${GREEN_TEXT}true${RESET_TEXT}
false=${RED_TEXT}false${RESET_TEXT}

echo "$OUTPUT" | sed "s/sys/${true}/g" | sed "s/never/${false}/g" | sed "s/none/${false}/g"
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you and best regards!

Comment: Don't use `echo`. Use `sed "s/sys/${true}/g;s/never/${false}/g;s/none/${false}/g" "$OUTPUT"`

Comment: @oliv `sed "s/sys/${true}/g;s/never/${false}/g;s/none/${false}/g" "$OUTPUT"` does not work.

Comment: Please show how the variable `$OUTPUT` is assigned. I actually meant to give a file as input to `sed`. If you do that the sed command will work.

Comment: `OUTPUT=$(sshnc $FILER "export-policy rule show -vserver *$VSERVER* -policy *$POLICY* -clientmatch $HOSTNAME -fields rorule,rwrule,superuser,clientmatch")`

It's a NetApp CLI command which I'm using to get needed details.

Comment: Retry using `sshnc ... | sed '...'`

Comment: Does not work.
`sshnc $FILER "export-policy rule show -vserver *$VSERVER* -policy *$POLICY* -fields rorule,rwrule,superuser,clientmatch" | sed -e "s/sys/${true}/g;s/never/${false}/g;s/none/${false}/g"`

Why should I not use `echo` ? I would like to know this

Comment: This is an unnecessary step since you want to reformat the output of the command through sed.

Comment: And how should the CLI look exactly without the echo?

Comment: Exactly like you pasted in your comment.

Comment: Well... By looking closer to the command, I doubt `*$VSERVER*` is correct and should be replaced by `"$VSERVER"`. Same for `$POLICY`

Comment: `*$VSERVER*` and `*$POLICY* `
This entries fits, it serves so that I don't have to write out the Vserver name and policy completely. Is more of a "like" function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this may be help you?

```
echo **-n** "$OUTPUT" | sed "s/sys/${true}/g" | sed "s/never/${false}/g" | sed "s/none/${false}/g"
```

Or

```
echo **-n** "$OUTPUT" | sed -e 's/sys/${true}/g' | sed -e 's/none/${false}/g' | sed -e 's/never/${false}/g'
```